# Upload pre-selected file with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm creating a photoshop extension where I need to save the file people are working on and upload it to a server. So I want the extension to be able to automatically choose the current file and upload it to my server.

Problem is I don't know how to pre-select a file for people. Here's my code so far:

```
        var app:Application = Photoshop.app;

        var doc:Document = app.documents.add();
        doc.selection.selectAll();

        var color:RGBColor = new RGBColor();
        color.red = 0;
        color.green = 0;
        color.blue = 255;

        doc.selection.fill(color);
        var saveOptions:JPEGSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
        //Add other PDF save options here.
        doc.saveAs(File.applicationStorageDirectory, saveOptions);

        var jsonOBJ:Object = {};
        jsonOBJ.option = "iphone";
        jsonOBJ.title = "c";
        jsonOBJ.description = "s";
        jsonOBJ.app_store_url = "iphone";
        jsonOBJ.tags = "c";
        jsonOBJ.temp_number = 1;

        var _service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        _service.url = "http://localhost:3000/designs";
        _service.method = "POST";
        _service.contentType = "application/json";
        _service.resultFormat = "text";
        _service.useProxy = false;
        _service.makeObjectsBindable = true;
        _service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,faultRX);
        _service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultRX);
        _service.showBusyCursor = true;
        _service.send( JSON.encode( jsonOBJ ) );

        function resultRX():void
        {
            trace(ResultEvent.RESULT);
        }
        function faultRX():void
        {
            trace(FaultEvent.FAULT);
        }

        var file:FileReference;  
        var filefilters:Array;  
        var req:URLRequest;

        filefilters = [ new FileFilter('Images', '*.jpg') ]; // add other file filters  
        file.browse(filefilters);
```

Comment: In browser based apps; you can't pre-select a file.  A user must manually select the file.  In AIR apps you can using the File API ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html ).  I'm not sure if "CS Extensions" give you access to the File API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a photoshop extension. I ended up using FileReference and link to the file. it worked. I dunno how to actually upload the image though. When I use file.upload(requestUrl), it sends along a wrong content type. –